# ObjC - Changing NSTextField stringValue causes exc_bad_access

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa

**What works**

I have a view with a `NSTextField` and a button:

When I click the button, a "card" is created with a title equal to the string in the text box. If no text is entered, the card's title resorts to some default value.

**Issue**

This works fine, but I would like the text box's string to reset every time I click the button. So I added `[inputField setStringValue:@""];` to try to do this, but Xcode gives me a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` issue when trying to access `aCard`'s `myTitle` member when attempting to access `Card`'s `drawRect` method.

Why would resetting `inputField`'s `stringValue` cause this error?

**Code and screenshots**

From the button press method:

```
if (![inputField.stringValue  isEqual: @""])
{
    [aCard setStringTitle:inputField.stringValue];
    [inputField setStringValue:@""]; // this line causes a problem!
}
```

Here's the Card's `setStringTitle` method:

```
-(void)setStringTitle:(NSString *)aString
{
    myTitle = aString;
    [[self viewWithTag:0] setStringValue:myTitle];
}
```

And Card's `drawRect` method:

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
{
    [super drawRect:dirtyRect];

    // Drawing code here.
    [myColor set];
    NSRectFill([self bounds]);

    NSLog(@"My title: %@",myTitle);
    NSTextField* cardTitle = [[NSTextField alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(10, 10, 80, 30)];
    [cardTitle setStringValue:myTitle];
    [cardTitle setBezeled:NO];
    [cardTitle setEditable:NO];
    [cardTitle setDrawsBackground:NO];
    [cardTitle setSelectable:NO];
    [self addSubview:cardTitle];
    NSLog(@"string title is added within card class");

}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: If you add a exception breakpoint what does your stack trace show

Comment: Add an exception breakpoint. Go to the "Breakpoint Navigator", click on the "+" at the bottom left, select "Add Exception Breakpoint." Run the app to get the breakpoint. When you hit the exception breakpoint **click debug continue** a couple of times and you will get a backtrace and more error info. Post that and an exact copy of Xcode/Debugger messages.

Comment: If you're going to access views via `viewWithTag:`, you're probably best off not using the default tag value of `0`.  Give your text field a unique tag in the xib.

Comment: Have you got ARC enabled?